# How to correctly update data in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the previous code that updates the interval data in the locale and in the browser without issue.

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: []}
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('file.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result =>
        this.setState({
          data: result.data}));
}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => componentWillMount(), 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.timer = null;
  }
```

Due to the fact that componentWillMount is now deprecated for use, I decided to rewrite the code. As a result, the data is updated in the locale, but not in the browser. Why? Please help me.

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      lang: 'ru'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadingData = fetch('file.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result =>
        this.setState({
          data: result.data}));
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.loadingData, 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.timer = null;
  }
```

Comment: There are significant differences between your old and new code: `componentWillMount` was a function, `this.loadingData` is a Promise. And you're not even calling it, `() => this.loadingData` wouldn't have the desired effect even if `this.loadingData` was a function. Try moving your fetch code back into a function, call that properly, and you should be good.

Comment: @digitalbreed Thank you. Can you suggest your solution with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here's an answer based on my comment. Also see how I clear the interval when the component will be unmounted.

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      lang: 'ru'
    }
  }

  loadData() {
      fetch('file.json')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(result =>
              this.setState({
                  data: result.data
              })
          );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.loadData();
      this.timer = setInterval(() => this.loadData(), 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
```

You may consider to use `setTimeout` and reinitiate this from within your fetch so that you can account for slow network etc.

Comment: I don't think `this.timer = null` is really necessary since it will be unmounted soon at that point anyway.

Comment: @MikeHanslo I agree, I took it over from Vlad's original code but I will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the "right" way to do it but you can just force the browser to refresh the page: `window.location.reload()`

Comment: Forced page refresh of course refreshes the data, but this is not the best solution ... I need an automatic refresh without reloading the page.

Comment: I imagine you have already tried updating state via ```setState()``` this will force React to re-render the components that are dependent on the state that is changed but this  may be difficult to do depending on how you are passing state between the components of your application. Are you using any boolean "visible/show" flags? You could toggle the state of these flags off and then on again to see if React forces the re-render